# log4j2 issue . Unable to log any thing either in console or in a file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, log4j, log4j2

I just updated from log4j 1.x to log4j2. Every thing was working fine in 1st version. Now after updating to log4j2 its not logging any thing .  i am pasting my code below. any one please help me out

This are my dependencies

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
        <type> jar</type>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
        <type> jar</type>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
        <type> jar</type>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
    </dependency>                                                
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
    </dependency>
```

this is my log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
    <Appenders>
        <console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT" includeLocation="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] [%c:%L] %m%n"/>

        </console>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Rolling" fileName="${sys:DOC_ROOT}/logs/UILogs-${sys:SERVER_NAME}-${sys:SERVER_ID}-${sys:SERVER_TYPE}.log"
                                 filePattern="${sys:DOC_ROOT}/logs/UILogs-${sys:SERVER_NAME}-${sys:SERVER_ID}-${sys:SERVER_TYPE}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] [%c:%L] %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="180" compressionLevel="9"/>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>



        <Async name="dev">
            <AppenderRef ref="DevSMTP" level="fatal"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" level="debug"/>
        </Async>
        <Async name="test">
            <AppenderRef ref="TestSMTP" level="fatal"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" level="debug"/>
        </Async>  
        <Async name="prod">
            <AppenderRef ref="ProdSMTP" level="fatal"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" level="info"/>
        </Async>
        <Async name="local">
            <AppenderRef ref="DevSMTP" level="fatal"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" level="debug"/>
        </Async>
        <Async name="">
            <AppenderRef ref="ProdSMTP" level="fatal"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" level="info"/>
        </Async>
        <Async name="">
            <AppenderRef ref="TestSMTP" level="fatal"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="debug"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" level="debug"/>
        </Async> 
        <Async name="">
            <AppenderRef ref="ProdSMTP" level="fatal"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" level="info"/>
        </Async>
        <Async name="lib">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling" level="info"/>
        </Async> 

    </Appenders>  

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="${sys:SERVER_TYPE}"/>
        </Root>        
        <root level="error">
      <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    </root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.ibatis" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="lib"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="java.sql" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="lib"/>
        </Logger>
         <Logger name="RollingRandomAccessFile" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="Rolling"/>
        </Logger>
        <logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace">
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</logger>

</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things to fix in the configuration:

**Dependencies:**

- There is a space ' ' character between `<type>` and `jar`. (Not sure if this causes any problem).

**Log4j2.xml configuration:**

- There are three `Async` appenders without a name. They MUST have names.
- There are two root appenders. There can be only ONE root appender in a configuration, so you need to remove one of them.
- Several Loggers do not have a level defined. If your intention is for the log level filtering to be done by the appenders, I recommend that you ensure that ALL events are passed to the appenders: I recommend you specify level TRACE on these loggers.
- The `<Loggers>` element does not have a closing `</Loggers>` tag. This may be the biggest problem.

Comment: Also, set <Configuration status="trace"... to get more info on log4j config problems.

Answer (score 0):

Are you receiving any related error? for example if it's the error: "ERROR StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogge" try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438871/log4j2-configuring) to solve your logging issues.